# firebase Function waiting too long to terminate

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions, it's great generally. Although the function below returns a response quickly, when I checked the GCP trace I saw the termination of that function usually takes 70-90 seconds. There is no other function that shows a similar termination time. Any idea, why does this happen? Thanks!

```
gameServerRouter.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  Logger.logSystem(req.url, false);

  return Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    res.send({ "ResultCode": 0 });
    return Promise.resolve();
  });

});
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be using `res.json()` to send back objects of data (it calls `res.send()` internally, but also sets all the correct headers).

Comment: I tried nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the response ultimately. The function won't terminate otherwise.

A solution would be:

```
  return Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    return res.send({ "ResultCode": 0 });
  });
```

Notice that the `then` method will return the response object which will be finally returned by the post function. A good practice would be to set relevant headers too.

Comment: Can you try without the logging?